# How to make an accumulated sum with constraints

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, constraints, cumsum

I need to sum values correspoding to a certain range of dates, and I need to do this for many subjects.

In the next example, df1 contains starting and ending dates for three subjects, and df2 contains dates and their corresponding values:

```
df1<-data.frame(sub=c("a","b","c"), 
                start=as.Date(c("2015/10/13","2015/10/13","2015/10/11")), 
                end=as.Date(c("2015/10/16","2015/10/18","2015/10/15")))

df2<-data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2015/10/11"), as.Date("2015/10/18"), "days"), 
                value=c(32,30,28,15,19,23,35,18))

> df1
  sub      start        end
1   a 2015-10-13 2015-10-16
2   b 2015-10-13 2015-10-18
3   c 2015-10-11 2015-10-15

> df2
        date value
1 2015-10-11    32
2 2015-10-12    30
3 2015-10-13    28
4 2015-10-14    15
5 2015-10-15    19
6 2015-10-16    23
7 2015-10-17    35
8 2015-10-18    18
```

I want to sum `value` in df2 from `start` date until `end`date in df1, and I want to do it for each `sub` (in the real problem there are many subjects (i.e. pairs of starting and ending dates), and so I thoght maybe I should use `for` loop).

I expect something like this:

```
sub sum
a   85
b   138
c   124
```

where a = 28+15+19+23, b = 28+15+19+23+35+18 and c = 32+30+28+15+19

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `mapply` would be to create a sequence of dates between `start` and `end` dates in `df1` and subset those dates from `df2` and `sum` the `value`.

```
df1$sum <- mapply(function(x, y) sum(df2$value[df2$date %in% x:y]), 
           df1$start, df1$end)


df1[c(1, 4)]
#  sub sum
#1   a  85
#2   b 138
#3   c 124
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `non-equi` join without using any loop

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1,  .(sub = sub, sum = sum(value)), 
      on = .(date >= start, date <= end), by = .EACHI][, .(sub, sum)]
#    sub sum
#1:   a  85
#2:   b 138
#3:   c 124
```

---

Or using `fuzzyjoin` in a `tidy` way

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_left_join(df2, df1, by = c(date = 'start', date = 'end'), 
        match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
  group_by(sub) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  sub   value
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a        85
#2 b       138
#3 c       124
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single SQL statement like this:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.sub, sum(b.value) as sum
  from df1 as a
  left join df2 as b on b.date between a.start and a.end
  group by a.sub")
```

giving:

```
  sub   sum
1   a    85
2   b   138
3   c   124
```